# register button has no function

Tags: asp.net, button, registration

Suddenly my register button is not performing any action other that validations. any idea?

here is my registration.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsValid)
        {
            cmd.Connection = con; //assigning connection to command
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //representing type of command
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UserData values(@Username,@Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@CustomerType,@DeliveryAddress,@Zip,@ContactNumber)";

            //adding parameters with value
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtLN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", (txtPW.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerType", RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryAddress", txtAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZip.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContact.Text);
            con.Open(); //opening connection
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  //executing query
            con.Close(); //closing connection
            label_register_success.Text = "Registered Successfully..";

        }
        else
        {
            label_register_success.Text = "Please check the registration errors";
        }
    }
    protected void ValidateUserName(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs arguments)
    {
        string UserName = arguments.Value;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE Username=@Username", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", UserName);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                arguments.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                arguments.IsValid = true;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void ValidateEmail(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs arguments)
    {
        string Email = arguments.Value;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE Email=@Email", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                arguments.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                arguments.IsValid = true;
            }
```

Its not performing the successful registration and the validations for the repeated username and email. please help me out, thanks!

Comment: actually it shows the validation for the repeated username but still, its not pushing through the successful registration.

Comment: Are those declarations for con and cmd really outside of any method?  Your `btnSubmit_Click` code looks way off.   Also, what happens when you step through it with the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering the validation via:

```
Page.Validate();
```

And pass in any validation groups you use as the parameter (if applicable) before checking IsValid, and see if that detects the errors.  I assume your Validate methods are called from CustomValidator controls?